# Rating algorithm seems off

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I'm writing a rating algorithm for locations in my application. The algorithm does the following:

`takes the average rating of a club and mulitplies by a club multiplier`

`a club multiplier is a decimal mulitplied against the average rating to account for a clubs impression against the total`

Currently my algorithm is the following:

`CLUB RATING = SUM(RATINGS FOR CLUB) / COUNT(RATINGS FOR CLUB)`

`CLUB MULTIPLIER = CLUB TOTAL NUMBER OF RATINGS / TOTAL NUMBER OF RATINGS FOR ALL CLUBS`

`WEIGHTED VALUE = CLUB RATING * CLUB MULTIPLIER`

I came up with this algorithm myself.

I imagined that figuring out the influence of the club by number of ratings against all clubs number of ratings is the multiplier and we multiply this against the standard average to determine the weighted average of this club against all clubs.

Here is my resulting dataset:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [locid] => 332
            [totalclubsnumratings] => 12321
            [clubaveragerating] => 4.4
            [clubnumratings] => 1121
            [clubmultiplier] => 9.0982874766659
            [weightedvalue] => 40.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [locid] => 329
            [totalclubsnumratings] => 12321
            [clubaveragerating] => 3.1
            [clubnumratings] => 909
            [clubmultiplier] => 7.3776479181885
            [weightedvalue] => 23.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [locid] => 1681
            [totalclubsnumratings] => 12321
            [clubaveragerating] => 4.7
            [clubnumratings] => 517
            [clubmultiplier] => 4.1960879798718
            [weightedvalue] => 20.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [locid] => 1710
            [totalclubsnumratings] => 12321
            [clubaveragerating] => 4.1
            [clubnumratings] => 505
            [clubmultiplier] => 4.0986932878825
            [weightedvalue] => 17.00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [locid] => 3312
            [totalclubsnumratings] => 12321
            [clubaveragerating] => 4.2
            [clubnumratings] => 398
            [clubmultiplier] => 3.2302572843113
            [weightedvalue] => 14.00
        )

)
```

The problem is I can't tell if its calculating correctly or not. Club with `locid 329` (the second club) has a higher amount of ratings but its average rating is much smaller versus the third club, with `locid 1681` who has a smaller number of ratings but higher average of club rating.

**Should I expect the ordering to have some clubs with a higher weighted value but a lower club average rating or am i missing a second algorithm that redetermines the club rating?**

I'd like someone to look at this and tell me what this algorithm is doing incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please post your implementation code?

Comment: By the way, if `CLUB MULTIPLIER = CLUB TOTAL NUMBER OF RATINGS / TOTAL NUMBER OF RATINGS FOR ALL CLUBS`, it can never be larger than 1.And it is moot to divide by the total number of ratings for all clubs, because that value is constant for all clubs and can shortened out.

Comment: @lxg ok than how should I equate the club multiplier. I'll post code tonight when I get home

Comment: Simply the number of votes. But, IMHO, your logic is flawed anyway: You have two dimensions –  quality of the club and quantity of the voters, and they are not really related. If you have a shitty club with lots of reviews, why should it have a better rating than a shitty club with a few reviews? You can not merge club quality and voter quantity into one figure, just like you can’t multiply millseconds and banana. And, on most websites featuring some sort of rating, you will always see both the rating and the number of voters separately.

Comment: @lxg  ok than can you assist with a valid solution.

Comment: @lxg I don't quite understand how quality of ratings and number of voters does not relate still.

Comment: As I said, I’d display the rating and the number of votes separately. And maybe implement some mechanism that will prevent penalizing clubs with few, extreme votes (1/10 or 10/10) – especially for fraud protection. For example, don’t display the rating until a club has received 10 votes from different IP addresses.

Comment: I think you might be confusing two things: The quality of the *club* and the quality of the *rating*. The quality of the rating can be considered higher (i.e. more reliable) the more votes you have (law of large numbers). But this doesn’t say anything about the club. If a thousand people think a club is lame, then, by your approach, the club would get a better rating than a club with a hundred “lame” votes – which doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Ok well I'd appreciate if you took a moment and help me create algorithms for both the quality of the club and the quality of a rating. I'm finding it hard to believe that there is no algorithm that determines the quality of a club based on its average rating and it's quality of rating as you put it, which to me is the multiplier in my algorithm

Comment: Don’t overthink it. Quality of the club = rating. Quality of the rating = number of votes (and maybe some fraud prevention features). As you don’t have more primary data, that’s all you can work with. There’s no sense in applying advanced mathematics here.

Comment: Although, what you *could* do is to apply statistical methods to improve the quality of the rating. For example, you could check if the median gives different results than the arithmetic mean. If so, you might want to create a combined value of both.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a club with 2 5.0 ratings is comparable to a club with 100 5.0s. There must be a way to determine this.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to determine the rating based on the weighted value so it represents a rating based on quality of the rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a hack to come up with reasonable uncertainties, first calculate the variance of the average vote, across all votes for all clubs.

Then for each club, call the standard deviation of its rating is `sqrt(variance * votes)`.  (This is factually wrong.  But will work well enough.)  And you have a median and a 95% confidence interval of 2 standard deviations to each side.

Now you can choose to be pessimistic about clubs, and give them each a rating of, say, 1 standard deviation below their median.  If you do this, then a club with 2 5.0 ratings will likely wind up worse than a club with a 4.5 rating after 100 votes.  To get to a truly top ranking you have to both do well, and have a lot of votes.

Comment: Can you please provide a numeric solution for this?

Comment: just checking in. if you can lay this out in math so i can explicitly see what to do that would be great.